# Centos trying to execute hello.cgi script fails

Tags: httpd, cgi

I'm trying to execute a simple hello world cgi script in the html directory but it fails.

**Error log:**

```
[Tue May 17 14:56:15.744954 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 29997] [client 192.168.1.1:16151] End of script output before headers: hello.cgi
[Tue May 17 15:00:12.474229 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 29998] [client 192.168.1.1:16597] AH01215: (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/html/hello.cgi' failed
[Tue May 17 15:00:12.475135 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 29998] [client 192.168.1.1:16597] End of script output before headers: hello.cgi
[Tue May 17 15:00:13.176640 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 29999] [client 192.168.1.1:16600] AH01215: (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/html/hello.cgi' failed
[Tue May 17 15:00:13.177591 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 29999] [client 192.168.1.1:16600] End of script output before headers: hello.cgi
[Tue May 17 15:00:13.640420 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 30000] [client 192.168.1.1:16603] AH01215: (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/html/hello.cgi' failed
[Tue May 17 15:00:13.641393 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 30000] [client 192.168.1.1:16603] End of script output before headers: hello.cgi
```

**httpd config:**

```
# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**hello.cgi file:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; # This is mandatory.
print "<h2>Hello world!</h2>";
```

Comment: Is perl actually installed?

Comment: yes and perl-CGI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the first line of your script file to the following and retry.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

If this fixes the issue then your script file contains '\r\n' instead of '\n' as the newline character which is usually the case when the script is not uploaded in ASCII mode from a Windows or MAC computer.

Comment: Great, now it works. Such a silly little error.